# Null Guard for Nested Objects With Hierarchy Path Recognition in C#

Tags: c#, .net-core, guard, c#-8.0, null-check

I'm trying to create a nested Guard method (or find an existing Guard library) that would throw an exception if any object in a nested hierarchy is NULL ***and include the name of the object hierarchy path up to and including NULL.*** I also want to avoid fluent API syntax of checking each object. Please assume example below.

**Assume the following hierarchy:**

```
Country.State.City.Person
```

**Example of usage I'm trying to achieve:**

```
Guard.ThrowIfNull(Country.State.City.Person);
```

or

```
Guard.ThrowIfNull(() => Country.State.City.Person);
```

**EXPECTED RESULT:**

if **Person** is NULL, then throw ArgumentNullException("**Country.State.City.Person**")

if **City** is NULL, then throw ArgumentNullException("**Country.State.City**")

if **State** is NULL, then throw ArgumentNullException("**Country.State**")

if **Country** is NULL, then throw ArgumentNullException("**Country**")

Comment: `Guard.ThrowIfNull(Country.State.City.Person);` is not going to work.... About the second one... I am wondering if an expression might help you out here....

Answer (score 2):

At minimum, I believe you'll need to pass an instance to the `Guard.ThrowIfNull` function in addition to the path you want to check.

I wrote a proof of concept below that exhibits the behavior you describe. It does not handle collections, however. (In the case that State is a collection, this code will fail for "Country.State.City".)

Usage:

```
Guard.ThrowIfNull(country, "Country.State.City.Person");
// Or
Guard.ThrowIfNull(country, x => x.State.City.Person);
```

Code:

```
public static class Guard
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Throws an ArgumentNullException if any portion of a given property path is null.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type to check.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="instanceToCheck">The instance to check</param>
    /// <param name="pathToCheck">The full path of the property to check. The path should include the name of the instance type.</param>
    public static void ThrowIfNull<T>(T instanceToCheck, string pathToCheck)
    {       
        var propsToCheck = pathToCheck?.Split('.');
        if (propsToCheck?.Any() != true)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(pathToCheck));
        }

        if (typeof(T).Name != propsToCheck.First())
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"The type of {nameof(instanceToCheck)} does not match the given {nameof(pathToCheck)}.");
        }

        if (instanceToCheck == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException($"{pathToCheck.First()}");
        }

        object currentObj = instanceToCheck;
        for (var i = 1; i < propsToCheck.Length; i++)
        {
            var prop = currentObj.GetType().GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == propsToCheck[i]);
            if (prop == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException($"The path, '{string.Join(".", propsToCheck.Take(i + 1))}' could not be found.");
            }

            currentObj = prop.GetValue(currentObj);
            if (currentObj == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException($"{string.Join(".", propsToCheck.Take(i + 1))}");
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Throws an ArgumentNullException if any portion of a given property path is null.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type to check.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="instanceToCheck">The instance to check</param>
    /// <param name="pathToCheck">The full path of the property to check.</param>
    public static void ThrowIfNull<T, TProp>(T instanceToCheck, Expression<Func<T, TProp>> pathToCheck)
    {
        ThrowIfNull(instanceToCheck, (typeof(T).Name + pathToCheck.ToString().Substring(pathToCheck.ToString().IndexOf("."))));
    }
}
```